# Installation Error in mac while installing Oracle Jdeveloper.

Tags: java, oracle, macos, jdeveloper

I am not able to install Jdeveloper on mac. I have done with setting path for jdk 
My command is :

```
sudo "/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk-9.0.1.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java" -jar /Users/Desktop/JAVA/jdev_suite_122100.jar
```

and getting this error:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerSpi: com.oracle.cie.common.dao.jaxb.JaxbDataHandlerSpiImpl Unable to get public no-arg constructor
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(ServiceLoader.java:581)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.getConstructor(ServiceLoader.java:672)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.access$1000(ServiceLoader.java:390)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNextService(ServiceLoader.java:1227)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$LazyClassPathLookupIterator.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1259)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$2.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1294)
    at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.hasNext(ServiceLoader.java:1379)
    at com.oracle.cie.common.dao.DataHandlerSpi.getDataHandlerProvider(DataHandlerSpi.java:81)
    at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.getDataHandlerProvider(DaoHelper.java:123)
    at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.parse(DaoHelper.java:170)
    at com.oracle.cie.gdr.helpers.DaoHelper.getRootWrapper(DaoHelper.java:316)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.getOptionsInfoDao(OptionsParser.java:516)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.parseOptionsDao(OptionsParser.java:189)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.<init>(OptionsParser.java:136)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.parser.OptionsParser.getInstance(OptionsParser.java:123)
    at com.oracle.cie.nextgen.common.inputs.impl.OUIOptions.<init>(OUIOptions.java:58)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javax.xml.bind.JAXBException
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
```

Comment: You should try asking this question on [the Oracle JDeveloper forum](https://community.oracle.com/community/java/java_development_tools/application_development_in_java/jdeveloper_and_adf). I admit it doesn't seem the liveliest of forums but you're more likely to find a JDev SME there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JDeveloper is not yet supported with JDK 9 - check the certification matrix for the specific JDK version for your JDeveloper version - http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/developer-tools/jdev/documentation/index.html